# Updating array afte doing a post request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, vue.js, vuejs2

it's my first time working with Vue and I'm trying to make a simple crud using Spring as backend. My problem is that when I send the actor with the post request, and I try to make a get request to get the new actors list, it doesn't get updated until I refresh the page.

This is part of the html that I want to display. Just a form and the list of actors that I bring from my DB.

```
  <v-flex>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="newActor.firstName"
    label="Nombre"
    prepend-icon="person"
  ></v-text-field>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex>
  <v-text-field class="ml-5"
    v-model="newActor.lastName"
    label="Apellido"
  > </v-text-field>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex>
    <v-btn :class="['white--text','green']" @click="addActor">Enviar</v-btn>
  </v-flex>

<li v-for="actor in actors" v-bind:key="actor.id" :class="['mt-5']">
      id = {{actor.actorId}}
      <br> 
      name = {{actor.firstName}}
      <br>
      apellido = {{actor.lastName}}
      <br>
      lastUpdate = {{actor.lastUpdate}}
    </li>
```

This is my vue script.

```
export default {
data() {
  return {
    alert: false,
    alertMessage: '',
    alertType: 'success',
    urlBase: 'http://localhost:8081/',
    newActor: 
    {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      lastUpdate: ''
    },
    background: 'yellow',
    actors: []
  }
},
methods: 
{
  getActors: function()
  {
    this.actors = []
    let self = this
    fetch(this.urlBase+'actors/all')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        for (var variable of myJson) {
          self.actors.push(variable);
        }
      });
  },
  addActor: function()
  {
    if (this.newActor.firstName != '' && this.newActor.lastName != '') 
    {
      let self = this
      fetch(this.urlBase+'actors/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.newActor),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
      .then(response => console.log('Success:', response)); 
      this.alert = true;
      this.alertMessage = "Usuario agregado con éxito"; 
      this.getActors(); //Here is where I tried to get the actors again.
      console.log(this.actors);
    }
    else
    {
      this.alert = true;
      this.alertType = 'error';
      this.alertMessage = "Usuario no registrado"; 
    }
  } 
},
created: function()
{
  this.getActors()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `this.getActors();` is called before the `fetch` method is done. That's the way javascript works.

You can try putting `this.getActors();` in the `then`.

Example :

```
if (this.newActor.firstName != '' && this.newActor.lastName != '') 
    {
      let self = this
      fetch(this.urlBase+'actors/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.newActor),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Success:', response); 
        this.alert = true;
        this.alertMessage = "Usuario agregado con éxito"; 
        this.getActors(); //Here is where I tried to get the actors again.
        console.log(this.actors);
      })
    }
```

Comment: it works, many thanks. Just for curiosity, but it's always this way with fetch requests?

Comment: ìt's always like that for all asynchronous functions : https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/javascript-execution-of-synchronous-and-asynchronous-codes-40f3a199e687